# Write a C socket inside a function

Tags: c, sockets

I'm new in sockets and I don't know if its possible to do what I'm trying. First of all, I've looked for more info in Google and in stackoverflow but I haven't found anything :(

Now I explain my problem. I have created client socket (with the functions socket y connect) in the main function with no problem. But then I call a function called sendframe() thet I've created, where I do some stuff and then I use the write function to put a message in the socket. The problem here is that I dont know why the write function gives an error (returns -1). I think the problem is that I haven't passed correctly the socket file descriptor, but I'm not sure (I'm not convinced that using only the file descriptor allows me to write in the socket...)

Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
    #include ...

void sendframe(int sockfd);

void main(void) {
//// Open the socket
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("open socket erorr\n");

    server = gethostbyname("192.168.20.155");
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = 1414;
    serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *) server->h_addr);
    bzero(&(serv_addr.sin_zero),8);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1)
        error("connect error\n");
        exit(-1);


   // ..... More code.....

   // Send frame
   sendframe(&sockfd);

}

void sendframe(int sockfd)
{
   // Some stuff...

    char *frame
    int num = write(sockfd,frame,strlen(frame));

}
```

Probably the answer is so easy, but I'm new in this. Any clue?

Comment: `sendframe(&sockfd);` and `void sendframe(int sockfd)` do not agree on the argumenttype. BTW: `void main()` is wrong, too. main() shall return int.

Comment: It looks like you are not connecting to host is it because you dont really want to use gethostbyname function? There is different one for getting server from IP.

Comment: Well, I first tried to use sendframe(sockfd), but as it didnt work I tried to change it. Now I've rebooted my computer and tryed again without the & and works (dont know why...). Now I have to fix the  strlen(frame) problem I commented in MByD answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendframe(&sockfd);` should be `sendframe(sockfd);` as `sendframe` expects an int, not `int *`.

Comment: @gaterido By the way you can call `perror()` to show an appropriate error message: 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html

Comment: I don't think this is a problem though, it looks like it is exiting when connecting, I don't mean that your point is not valid, I just think that is even one step ahead.

Comment: Thanks! That solved half of the problem. Now I receive only 1 byte, but its because strlen(frame) does not return the number of bytes of the unsigned char pointer. I'll google it to find a solution ;)